# How live audio streaming and downloading to happen simultaneously in IOS using Objective c

Tags: objective-c, streaming, avplayer, audio-streaming, android-download-manager

I am creating one application with live audio streaming, I wanted live audio streaming and downloading to happen simultaneously (like WhatsApp files). Please let me know if someone can help me or guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `AVAssetResourceLoader` between your `AVPlayer` and The Internet to allow caching while you stream.

Here are some examples I found on github:

1. [AVAssetResourceLoader](https://github.com/leshkoapps/AVAssetResourceLoader)
2. [VIMediaCache](https://github.com/vitoziv/VIMediaCache)